# The unexpected behavior of an tuple in this regular expression example

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I tested this regular expression

```
test_reg = r"(?<=\(|\s)\d+\s?(?=((?:\s*(?:wh|www)[1-9]?\s?){1,3}))\1\b"
```

on the following three examples:

```
high energy densities (695 wh www ) at
high energy densities (695 wh www) at
high energy densities (695 wh www at
```

From the [result (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/WoKnCF/1), the ')' in the first example somehow makes the match failed, and delete it solves the problem. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `((?:\s*(?:wh|www)[1-9]?\s?){1,3})` capturing group #1 captures the optional whitespace in `high energy densities (695 wh www ) at` that us right after `www` and `)`. When the value is consumed with `\1`, there is no way to re-match this part of string since backtreferences are non-backtracking'able. Thus, the `\1` value with space at the end fails since `\b`, the word boundary, is not matching the location between the space and `)` (both are non-word chars).

Hence, the `\s?` at the end of Group 1 pattern should be removed, or moved (`\s?` or `\s*`) to the end of the expression:

```py
test_reg = r"(?<=[(\s])\d+\s?(?=((?:\s*(?:wh|www)[1-9]?){1,3}))\1\b"
test_reg = r"(?<=[(\s])\d+\s?(?=((?:\s*(?:wh|www)[1-9]?){1,3}))\1\b\s?"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoKnCF/2).